# Laravel old values plus newly checked values in edit template

Tags: laravel

In my `edit.blade`, I would like to show categories that were checked before by user + user can check new categories. So if a validation error occurred, the newly checked categories do not become unchecked.

This is what I have now:

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <input type="checkbox" id="category_id" name="category_id[]" value="{{ $category->id }}"
    {{ $category->posts->contains($post->id) ? 'checked' : '' }}
    @if (old('category')==$category->id) ? 'checked' : '' @endif>
    <label for="{{$category->id}}"> {{$category->category_name}}</label>
@endforeach
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

put the previously selected items in an array in controller and pass it to the view. like

```
$previouslySelected = [1, 3, 5];
```

and then you use the `old` helper to show the selected options.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category_id[]" value="{{ $category->id }}"
class="form-check-input" id="category{{ $category->id }}"
@if (in_array($category->id, old('category_id', $previouslySelected ))) checked @endif>
```

this will first check the values in `$previouslySelected` array. and when the validation fails, will check the values from old values.